# Why background-image:url() replace slash bar on url?

Tags: php, mysql, server

I'm trying get a url from MySQL database and display on `<img>` on PHP file, I get url perfect but when I put on `background-image:url` always disapear slash bar `/`.

**My database with url**

[image: 1]

**My code**

I get from database url using a query and I put:

[image: 2]

**my generate code (chrome console)**

[image: 3]

**Why slash bar was disapeared?**

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE (using another part of code)**
[image: 4]

Comment: That's unlikely to happen by itself. What Chrome Console shows may not necessarily be the raw HTML source either. Note how it switched the single for a double quote. -- Anyway, try html escaping.

Comment: `background-image:url(img/concurso/".$_SESSION['id_usuario']."/".$salida[2].")` try without . at start

Comment: but in other parts of the application if you show me the full path, check my update please

Comment: You close the style attribute with the single quote in the `url(`. Try using escaped double quotes for the `background-url(`.

Comment: Why screenshots? Just paste the code, makes it easier to answer question.

Comment: What is the update? It works now?

Comment: @Andrew sorry, I'm using another computer to programmer without internet then I'm connect a Pendrive then It's better take screenshots.. i'm so sorry

Comment: @pr0metheus I can't delete first slash bar because I need to return to the previous folder using `./`

Comment: @chris85 no, still not works, it's a screenshots from another part of my webapp, using the same method works perfect and I can see slash bar on chrome console, but here don't works, it's so strange..

Comment: @chris85 You have reason.... I was closing style attribute, put your answer to accept it, that works perfect, thanks and I'm so sorry to everyone to take screenshots instead paste my code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing the style attribute with the single quote in the `background-url(`. Escaped double quotes for the `background-url(` should resolve the issue or only outputting the id and the image location with PHP. With the latter suggestion you can use double quotes for the attribute and single quotes for the `background-url`.